# "How can I detect multiple Gaussian curves in laser pulse data from a Rigol oscilloscope and photodiode?"

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, edge-detection, oscilloscope

I have acquired an wave form file generated by Rigol oscilloscope, This wave form file contains laser pulses train represented by several gaussian curves as shown in this following figure: [waveform file acquired from the Rigol oscilloscope showing the ramp pulses and the stable pulses with their peaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbKfq.png). The point that these curves can not be seen correctly unless i zoomed into the picture to be able to see each gaussian curve as shown in this picture: [example for one of the Gaussian curves of each of the laser pulses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5qJ6.png) . my question is how to be able to detect these gaussian curves and find the area under these curves ?

I am expecting to have a new window with the laser pulses train graph highlighting each of the laser pulses gaussian graphs, maybe highlighting the are under each curve with printing how much is the area under each curve.